# jQuery - hide parent if img src has no image path

Tags: jquery

I have a OL on page, with each LI containing an img tag. However, some of those img src attributes only contain the thumbnail generator code, but no image path. I need to hide the parent LI for each such img.

My HTML:

```
<ol class="flex-control-thumbs">
<li><img src="graphic.jpg?action=thumbnail"></li>
<li><img src="?action=thumbnail"></li>
<li><img src="graphic.jpg?action=thumbnail"></li>
</ol>
```

IF not for the action variable, I could just check length:

```
$(".flex-control-thumbs li").each(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.find('img[src=""]').text().length > 62) {
        self.hide();
    }
});
```

So I'm thinking that to accommodate the action variable, I either need to check to see if the total src length is greater than x characters OR I need to find certain characters that I know will always be in the src IF an image path is present, such as '.jpg'. I cannot figure out how to get either method to work.

Comment: First of all I would suggest to solve the cause of the issue, the broken reference, not curing the symptom.

Comment: Next, if you _really_ cannot do that (why not?) then I'd use some url parser to be on the safe side to not miss interpret the references.

Comment: you can try this `$('img:not([src*="."])').parent().hide()`. This will find all the img that dont have a period in their src and then select that parent and hide it.

Comment: I agree with Mr. @arkascha . Revise src attribute generation code. For quick fix @Pedro Estrada's code looks like solvation. But if you have many such broken img tags on page it is better to add parent OL class for selector `.flex-control-thumbs img:not([src*="."])` . Or there is a chance to hide smth important.

Comment: I don't have control over the output of the OL, but the responses from Pedro and Barada work like a charm (I did use Barada's additional suggestion). Happy to mark as correct if someone posts as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onerror` event on the `img` tags:

```
<ol class="flex-control-thumbs">
    <li><img src="graphic.jpg?action=thumbnail" onerror="hideParent()"></li>
    ...
</ol>
```

JS:

```
function hideParent() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
}
```

Comment: The request will be done anyway... And you will see a flash of style.